# Border based on th colspans

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have a fairly basic html question that is, at least to me, surprisingly hard to solve. Searching the net hasn't yielded anything so far.

If I have the following table (arbitrarily simple, just for example's sake):

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <th colspan = "3">Monday</th>
        <th colspan = "2">Tuesday</th>
        <th colspan = "2">Wednesday</th>
        <th colspan = "1">Thursday</th>
        <th colspan = "2">Friday</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Event 1 on Monday</td>
            <td>Event 2 on Monday</td>
            <td>Event 3 on Monday</td>
            <td>Event 1 on Tuesday</td>
            <td>Event 2 on Tuesday</td>
            <td>Event 1 on Wednesday</td>
            <td>Event 2 on Wednesday</td>
            <td>Event 1 on Thursday</td>
            <td>Event 1 on Friday</td>
            <td>Event 2 on Friday</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

The result should something like this (I did this manually, just to show what I want):
[image: desired result]

Although I would obviously prefer one one line instead of two and I don't want to do it manually. It should take the colspan of the header to get a border across all rows.

Answer (score 0):

Use nth-child in css,there is no other way to give border according to the colspan in **css**,,,

```
table th,table tr td:nth-child(3),table tr td:nth-child(5),table tr td:nth-child(7),table tr td:nth-child(8){
    border-right:1px solid black;
}
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/c5bA4/1/)

You can do it using jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var i=0;
    $('tr th:not(:last-child)').each(function(index){
        var th=$(this);
        th.css('border-right','1px solid black');
        i=i+parseInt(th.attr('colspan'));
        $('tr td:nth-child('+i+')').css('border-right','1px solid black');

  });
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/c5bA4/6/)

Answer (score 0):

I solved a similar problem like this:

```
table {
  position: relative;
}

thead > tr:first-of-type th:not(:first-of-type)::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  top: 0;
  border: 2px solid black;
  height: calc(100% - 3px);
}
```

The pseudo-element spans the entire height of the table.

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/fvL5atm1/)